# Javascript library to force aspect ratio of HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, aspect-ratio

Is there any Javascript library that could force an HTML node (mostly images and div) to keep their aspect ratio while resized?

This would be particularly useful to resize the height of an element when its width is constrained by the size of the window.

**Note**: if that can be done in pure CSS, I'm buying it!

Comment: http://techpp.com/2008/08/02/how-to-resize-the-images-using-css-without-losing-the-aspect-ratio/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757782/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-when-scaling-image-using-one-css-dimension-in-ie6

Comment: [Here's an article about a somewhat more complicated technique.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/)

Comment: @Derek only works with images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/J2s3C/

Here's the code:

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

For other elements, it will be a *bit* more complicate.

Here a second demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5BgXk/ :

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="content"></div></div>

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 33.33%; /* Set ratio here */
    height: 0;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;    
}
```

Comment: Well it will only work with images as they have a native aspect ratio. `div` don't have aspect ratios so it's impossible for the browser to set an appropriate height.

Comment: I mean, if in your example you replace `img` with `div`, where/how would you set the wanted aspect ratio?

Comment: @Matthieu - Here's how you do it with elements other than `<img>`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5BgXk/

Comment: Great! It worked, I only had to add `height: 100%` also on the image *inside* the `div` keeping the ratio.

Comment: I edited your answer to add the second code snippet. I had some problems with Safari and it was fixed setting `height: 100%` instead of `0` for the `#wrapper`.

Comment: Oops, actually no the `height: 0` is best, it's just that in Safari any `img` inside the content without a fixed size will have to have `position: absolute` to be displayed (else it will have height=0 because of the #wrapper)... But that `position: absolute` is not good for me... I'm looking for a better solution

Comment: I asked a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276367/forcing-aspect-ratio-with-css-doesnt-work-on-safari (for anyone having the same problem)