# Fit images to container size keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image

I can't find a way to display the thumbnails on [this page](http://www.lolaartgallery.com/manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=39) as fitting into boxes of same dimensions (height:122px and width: 178px) without changing their respective aspect ratio.
I don't know the thumbnails original dimensions.
I have several nested `divs` as you can see, and the one that is of class `.picture1` has those dimensions, but the images do not fit into this div.
Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this meant to be just a html/css solution or are you considering javascript?

Comment: it is better if it is just html/css, but I can do jquery. thank you @Bruno

Comment: Have a look at the following  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757782/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-when-scaling-image-using-one-css-dimension-in-ie6

Comment: thanks but it is more complex in my case (several divs) and this doesn't work. Moreover, sometimes thumbnails are portrait sometimes they are landscape.

Comment: In that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: I tried that already but it assumes taht the image already has width and height in css but I don't know the original dimensions so I can't specify this in css.

Comment: Any reason why you'd want to use jQuery, when the pure CSS version, using `max-width` and `max-height` works fine?

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo no reason I am fine with pure css, but I cannot make max-width and max-height work with this case. Did you check the link?

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo I am testing with max-height max-width but it crops the image.

Comment: Not being able to use css properties to establish width or height of images sometimes happens when you access those properties before the images are loaded. In some instances, when images are loaded from cache, they also have no width or height. The website is using jQuery so maybe try a plugin like [this] (https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to resize your images after they have loaded.

Comment: @louis I added the `max-width` and `max-height` to the `.work-view img` class. This worked fine in Chrome and Firefox, without cropping the img.

Comment: @louis Have you considered not using as many divs to contain you image? They don't seem to serve any specific purpose.

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo I just tried max-width:100%; max-height:100%; which does not resize small enough and also max-width:168px; max-height:122px; which crops the image.  The multiple divs are used in jquery to  perform different actions, I can't remove them.

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo can you send a screen capture of it?

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo  actually I think using `max-height=100%` and `max-width=100%` for `.work-view img` works partially, but it doesn't resize to the right container...any idea why?

Comment: @louis It's because of the many divs you are using. The 100% relates only to the immediate parent of the img. You would need to apply the 100% width to all divs except the main parent, and eliminate any padding.

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo ok I just applied 100% to the intermediate divs and the dimensions to the final container....doesn't work...the vertical image is cropped....I am gonna try to eliminate padding

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo ok that is better like this. I also put `display:block` to the divs. Now how to center the img into the immediate parent?

Comment: @louis If you apply `text-align: center;` to the `<li>` your images will be centered inside the containers

Comment: @cowcowmoomoo thank you. But they are centered only horizontally, I would like them to be also centered vertically.

Comment: @louis Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul)

Answer (score 7):

IS this really a problem. After checking your page its quite simple that if you add the below class the images fit inside the comtainer

> ```
>     .work-view img {
>       max-height: 100px;
>       padding: 5px 5px 2px;
>       max-width: 150px;}
> ```

[image]

Comment: The question requires that the image needs to maintain its aspect ratio. If the image is smaller than the div it will not line up perfectly either.

Comment: This code example has been updated to use `max-width` and `max-height` which keeps aspect ratio.