# Preserve image aspect ratio with the height fixed

Tags: html, css

I am working with some icons in a table and I am looking to keep the aspect ratio of the icons.

The heights all have to be the same (18px) but the width can vary.

I have seen other solutions for these when the width is fixed and height is set to auto like below [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757782/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-when-scaling-image-using-one-css-dimension-in-ie6)

```
img {
  width:  75px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Some sample code is below for my table (at least just one cell in the table)

```
<td class="set_symbol" style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="/static/img/symbols_large/Gatecrash_Uncommon.gif" style="height: 18px;">
</td>
```

What I would like to do is to keep the height of the image at 18px and have the width be whatever fits the aspect ratio.

Also, I have no qualms about browsers. So if it takes CSS3 or whatever, doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you can try `<img src="/static/img/symbols_large/Gatecrash_Uncommon.gif" style="max-height: 18px;width: 100%;>`. Though I am not sure if thats what you want to do.

Comment: @acdcjunior Thanks, in my fervor I forgot it.

Comment: @stackErr I actually tried that and since the original images are 200px to 300px wide, it gives them a very wide look. I would like to preserve the aspect ratio while keeping the height at 18px.

Comment: Normally it should be `height: 18px; width: auto;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I would like to do is to keep the height of the image at 18px and have the width be whatever fits the aspect ratio.

This does what you want:

```
img { 
    height: 18px;
}
```

[**See demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/fyMSx/2/)

[image: sample image]

Keep in mind, `max-heigth` can be used instead of `height` if you want to keep small images small.