# Firefox scale image so that its height is 100 px

Tags: html, image, css, firefox

I am loading images of various sizes and dimensions into my website.
Chrome, Opera and Safari all stretch the image so, that it doesn't look unnaturally stretched or skewed. 
Firefox keeps the width of the original image and sets the image height to 100px.
This results in `50x100`, `150x100` and `2000x100` images.
[image]
On the left side you see Chrome, on the right one you see Firefox.
I want all images to be exactly 100px high.

The image class looks like this

```
 img.image-message {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-height: 100px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Setting only `height` and `width` doesn't change a thing:

```
 img.image-message {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        height: 100px;
        width: auto;
    }
```

View live example at [metahill.com](http://www.metahill.com/).
You can use this user to login:

```
Username: test_t
Password: meta_hill_t
```

Comment: Remove max-height: 100px?

Comment: If you want to keep the aspect ratio, you can set width to auto like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757782/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-when-scaling-image-using-one-css-dimension-in-ie6

Comment: @beta0x64 I want all images be 100px high. See the correct screenshot of chrome.

Comment: @wendelbsilva The width _is_ set to `auto`.

Comment: You have 2 options, sent max-width to auto or always scale image to 100px. To scale to 100px you need to remove max-height and max-width and set height to 100px and width to auto. The resizing to 100px is only bad if someone post an image smaller than 100px. In that case, the image quality will not be good.

Comment: @wendelbsilva Have you actually tried that? It doesn't work that way over here.

Comment: @poitroae maybe Im getting the question wrong. [http://jsfiddle.net/TC2re/](http://jsfiddle.net/TC2re/)

Comment: @wendelbsilva I see it seems to work there. Do you have any idea why it does not work on http://www.metahill.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I think I've identified the root of your problem in the CSS. It actually isn't directly a style of the `<img>` element, which is what made it so hard to pin down. It lies in this definition in chat.css:

```
#chat .chat-entry > .chat-entry-message {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-o-box;
    display:box;
    padding: 3px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The problem you see in Firefox relates to the `display: -moz-box`, which, as [explained by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-flex), causes children (such as the `<img>` elements you're having trouble with) of the styled element to grow to fill their parent. Changing the definition to something like:

```
#chat .chat-entry > .chat-entry-message {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

will fix the observed problem, though I'm not sure if all those variants of `display: box` were there for some other purpose. (So I can't say if this fix will affect anything else.) Anyways, hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to try helping further!

Answer (score 1):

Set the height to 100px, not the max height. The width will follow automatically to the height unless specifically declared.

Comment: Have you actually tried it in e.g. Firebug? Leaving it at only `img.image-message { height:100px;padding-bottom: 2px;}` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I have similar code in a project I am working on, I'll double check and update if the answer is different, but I believe that is all I am having to do

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your code and mine, but the solution I provided works for my situation.

Comment: I have another situation where I do not set any static height or widths and only place max values. I do not have min values declared, and that situation works as well